# asp.net + Testing timezone

Tags: asp.net, timezone

I am try storing my date values in UTC format into my SQL Server DB and then convert them to local time for displaying, seem to work fine, I can see that my DB date values stored are different(I presume it's converted to UTC already), retrieving it and display is also accurate until I try to test a different timezone by changing it in the Date and Time option(right bottom of Windows time settings in the task bar) so to "migrate" myself. Apparently, the dates still remain as I am in my own country even though the timezone which I changed to has a 3 hrs difference.

Can somehow please advice on a way to test the date display on a different timezone?

Thanks.

Storing date values to SQL Server:

```
DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse(startDateTime).ToUniversalTime();
DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Parse(endDateTime).ToUniversalTime();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDateTime", dateFrom));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDateTime", dateTo));
```

Retrive from DB and Display:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();
date = DateTime.Parse(dr["StartDateTime"].ToString()).ToLocalTime();
                      litDateTimeFrom.Text = date.ToString("dd MMM yy hh:mm tt");
date = DateTime.Parse(dr["EndDateTime"].ToString()).ToLocalTime();
                      litDateTimeTo.Text = date.ToString("dd MMM yy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I am assuming that you have changed time zone information on the server machine (because that is what will be used in `ToLocalTime` method). If not then that's what you need to do first for testing.

Secondly, have you tried restarting IIS (or your web application) after changing the system time zone? That is necessary because time-zone information could have been cached within .NET framework (in `TimeZoneInfo` class).

Said all that, to me, this does not make sense. Typically, time-zone information need to flow from user (client) machine because you want to show user local time (as relevant to his time-zone). So it would mean that you need to figure out the current user's time zone based on a) culture info from browser or b) what is stored in his profile data (perhaps country or actual time-zone) c) similar scheme. Once, user time-zone is known, you can use 
`TimeZoneInfo` class to convert UTC time to corresponding local time.

Comment: I am actually following this example: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081507-1.aspx I am quite confused because I thought I can use .tolocaltime method to convert a utc to localtime without needing to takecare of offsettings

Comment: @user415795, there is really no confusion. If you read carefully the article that you have sighted, the author is also saying the same. He is using `DateTime.ToLocalTime` for converting to **server time** - exact quote is *"Given a time in UTC, the .NET Framework makes it easy to convert it to server time. Just use the DateTime class's ToLocalTime() method"*. Server time is not same as user's local time - you can have two users in different time zone and server in third then all three will have different local times.